# EC2 scheduler doesn't stop instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduler

I have a scheduler with 2 periods:

- #1 `begintime=00:00`, `endtime=00:30` on the first day of the month = `monthdays=[1]`
- #2 `endtime=18:00` on `monday-sunday` (stop manual starts at the end of the day)

Seems that `endtime=00:30` on the first period doesn't work and instance only stops at `18:00`

What I am missing in this configuration?

Comment: Are you referring to [Instance Scheduler | Implementations | AWS Solutions](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes